# Trouble using atan2 to get the angle of a collision in box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, atan2

So I'm using `box2d` to handle physics and collisions in `libGDX`. I'm trying to figure out the angle of the collision so that I can apply certain effects at a given angle.

Doing some research, I found that atan2 should be the math function I need to get the correct angle, but it's returning curious results. For a contact that should be in the 2nd quadrant, I'm getting angles of less than 90. For contacts that are in the 3rd and 4th quadrants, I'm getting positive numbers for the contact angle. Does anyone have any insight as to what I could be doing wrong here?

```
float other_x = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[0].x * GameScreen.BOX_TO_WORLD;
float other_y = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[0].y * GameScreen.BOX_TO_WORLD;
float playerXpos = this.getX();
float playerYpos = this.getY();

float damageAngle = (float)Math.atan2((other_y - playerYpos), (other_x - playerXpos));

damageAngle = (float) (damageAngle * (180d/Math.PI));
```

And yes, that index of the world manifold does have coordinate information in it. I just can't seem to figure out why `atan2` is returning those values.

*edit* So I'm thinking that the problem isn't with atan2, but rather with the contact information that's being returned by the WorldManifold. So I guess my question is, what could be the problem, such that contact information would be off like this?

Comment: What's an example input and output to `atan2` you're confused by?

Comment: Actually I'm thinking the problem is the input. For example I'm looking at a case where the player coordinates are at x = 332, and the contact shows its x coordinates as being x = 388, which is impossible, considering the contact has occurred to the top left of the centre of the player..

Comment: Show us a list of sets of inputs and outputs, and tell us what you expected for each set.

Comment: I've actually solved this. The contact information is correct for the world manifold, but the getX() getY() information isn't returning info for the centre of the player, rather a corner. Adjusting for this fixes the problem.